# Coordinate Transformation Law (Tensors)

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I am reading *Vector and Tensor Analysis* by Borisenko and Tarapov.

Early in its definition of tensors, it describes a transformation to a new coordinate system by

$x_i' = \alpha_{i'k}x_k + X_{0i}$, where $\alpha_{i'k}$ is the "cosine of the angle between the i'th axis of the new system and the kth axis of the old system".

My question is: how does the introduction of the kth index work? For example, when finding $x_1'$, does k assume the value of i, so $x_i' = \alpha_{i'1}x_1 + X_{01}$ ? Or is there an implicit sum over all kth elements?

Comment: There is am implicit summation over $k$ (Einstein's rule). In your statement, I think it must be "$\alpha_{ik}$ is the cosine...". A way to look at this tensor relation is in matrix form. $\alpha_{ik}$ is a matrix, and you get the column of new coordinates multiplying the column of old coordinates by this matrix (from the left). The $X_{0i}$ is just a vector, which makes your transformation affine.

Comment: OK, great. I was hesitant to assume Einsten's rule as I've only seen the repeated index in the superscript, not the subscript. Thank you for pointing out my error in defining $\alpha_{i'k}$, it has been corrected.